# Control Qt GUI app with Linux service

Tags: linux, qt

I need to start/stop Qt GUI app through Linux(14.04) service.
There is a simple startup script which sets-up paths, QML libs and plugins which works if I run it as a user. This action is requested when USB is detected. But I cannot start GUI from the script that is handling USB action (or I don't know hot to do that).

I tried to add simple service in /etc/init.d/ which woud start/stop GUI, but it still doesn't work.
Next thing I tried is QtService , but following code doesn't start service and gives no info what the problem is.

```
QProcess *process = new QProcess(this);
QString file = "/opt/test/qmltest";
process->start(file);
```

Is there any example on how this is done?

Comment: Does this code actually works, when you run it as a regular program (not from init.d script)?

Comment: It's something I've seen in other SO posts. But it might be that it is not the best way for the my problem.